# Send POST request and read response. IOException when conn.getInputStream()

Tags: java, android, httprequest, httpurlconnection, httpresponse

I searched everywhere and couldn't fix my problem. I have AsyncTask, in doInBackground I have:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
 try {
    URL url = new URL(stringURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Allow Outputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    // Don't use a cached copy.
    onn.setUseCaches(false);
    // Use a post method.
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", params[0].length);

    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    out.write(params[0]);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    int ch;
    StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
    while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){
       b.append( (char)ch );
    }
    String s = b.toString();

}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am calling my Async Task like that:`new httpRequestResponseTask().execute(byteArray);`

Every single time I am sending the request successfully and after I try to read Response I am getting
`java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection...`
when I call `conn.getInputStream()`. I get the same exception when I call
`conn.getResponseCode()` and `conn.getResponseMessage()`.

I can see that the server gets my **request** and send **response** successfully. But I am not getting it.

I tried many thinks (some of them crazy) just to test like:

*I put `conn.connect();` after setting Properties - same IOexception

*Not closing the OutputStream - same IOexception

*adding big timeouts like

```
     conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
     conn.setConnectTimeout(35000);
```

**The response should be 57 bytes so the timeout is more then enough.**
No change.

*I try to take the InputStream with url.OpenStream(). It just hangs and nothing happend.

*I tried with different Properties like `Accept-Encoding` and with less Properties.

*I checked the url and there is no space in it. The url is something like this:
`http://example.com:8080`.

I don't have proxy. I use my personal phone as a Wi-Fi hotspot and I test the program with my work phone. It's with android 6.0 but the project is set to 4.4 kitkat.

Should I wait somehow or do something else? I am out of ideas...

**UPDATE EXCEPTION STACK**

Without Content-Length

```
12-21 14:38:09.516 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{example.com:8080, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=*.*.*.* cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
12-21 14:38:09.516 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
12-21 14:38:09.516 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
12-21 14:38:09.516 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:918)
12-21 14:38:09.516 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:802)
12-21 14:38:09.516 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
12-21 14:38:09.516 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.xmltestservers.MainActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:172)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.xmltestservers.MainActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:125)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:200)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
12-21 14:38:09.517 5481-5572/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:   ... 14 more
```

With Content-Length

```
12-21 14:40:42.783 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{example.com:8080, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=*.*.*.* cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
12-21 14:40:42.784 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
12-21 14:40:42.785 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
12-21 14:40:42.785 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:918)
12-21 14:40:42.785 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:802)
12-21 14:40:42.786 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
12-21 14:40:42.786 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
12-21 14:40:42.786 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
12-21 14:40:42.786 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.xmltestservers.MainActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:169)
12-21 14:40:42.786 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.xmltestservers.MainActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:125)
12-21 14:40:42.787 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
12-21 14:40:42.787 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-21 14:40:42.787 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
12-21 14:40:42.787 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
12-21 14:40:42.788 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
12-21 14:40:42.788 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-21 14:40:42.788 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=57 content=f1f1f1340079c1eed5d9043324501c4ae6700647e093ea8a18b2e42c9d2acbd8...
12-21 14:40:42.789 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:200)
12-21 14:40:42.790 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
12-21 14:40:42.790 7729-7837/com.xmltestservers W/System.err:   ... 14 more
```

Comment: Check post method from here https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/get-and-post-request-using-default-http-client/

Comment: my code is doing the same thing like postJson method and it's not working. the only difference is that his Content-Type is application/json and mine is text/html. I do it exactly like this https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/ and I am still getting the same IOException

Comment: You are posting html content as a byte array?

Comment: Also, read the other exception. `EOFException: \n not found: size=0`. So, there's no new line and there's nothing coming back from the server at all

Comment: `You are posting html content as a byte array?` - No. Should I change it to someting else. about the other comment - I added one with Content-Length. This exception is after the `IOException` so `EOFException: \n not found: size=0` is because of the `IOException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the response didn't have any headers and I think this was the problem. I tried it with `HTTPClient` and didn't work because there were no headers in the response (I think the exception was not valid HTTP Response). After that I tried with `Socket` and it worked. Here is the code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(url.getHost(), url.getPort());
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.write(hardcodedRequest);
out.flush();

InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();

byte[] resp = new byte[hardcodedResponse.length];
int res = inStream.read(resp);

//Check if the response is the correct one.
if (!Arrays.equals(resp, hardcodedResponse) && res != hardcodedResponse.length) {

}
out.close();
```

I knew what was the response suppost to be so I hardcoded it and compare it with the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to read the response

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
```

Comment: Just test it. The same IOException. I also tried with `InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());`

Comment: the byte array needs to be "UTF-8" encoded when you pass it as a paramter, so if you are extracting it from a string use stringVar.getBytes("UTF-8") method

Comment: could you publish the exception stack

Comment: nice, this is basicly caused by content length header

Comment: I found that  some of the newer versions of android, there is a bug with recycled url connections, try this : 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
    urlConnect.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
}